# How to delete huge number of firewall rules (Windows server 2019)?

Tags: windows, powershell, netsh, windows-server-2019

I have 12 servers (session hosts) with tens of thousands firewall rules on each of them. Rules are creating when users are logging in and system is not deleting them when the're logging off (probably a bug which was fixed in WS2016, but in 2019 is here again).

I have tried to delete the rules with powershell's **Remove-NetFirewallRule**, but it's useless because of a performance. It takes 33 hours to delete 40k rules (20 rules per minute). Now I'm trying to achieve it with netsh.exe which is much quicker (1000 rules per minute), but I'm unable to find out how to filter out rules with "Any" in profile (these I want to keep).

I have tried to filter the rules with powershell and then push it to netsh:

```
$rulesToRemove = Get-NetFirewallRule | where {$_.profile -ne "Any"} | select displayName

foreach($rule in $rulesToRemove) { netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$rule }
```

and it's working for some rules and for others not - "No rules match the specific criteria". I tried to push displayName, name and several other values, but most of the rules simply didn't match the criteria. The only condition here is the fw rule name, so I tried to get the names with netsh and I got something like this for example:

> @{Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.11.6.17763_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?mc-resource://Microsoft.Windows.Cortana/resources/PackageDisplayName}

and even this didn't work for netsh as rule name :(.

QUESTION: Is there a way how to delete tens of thousands FW rules by script in a reasonable time?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are writing `select` (short for `Select-Object`) without `-ExpandProperty`. If you omit `-ExpandProperty`, you get OBJECTS with a `displayName` property. If you just want the `displayName` property as a list of strings, you would write `Select-Object -ExpandProperty displayName`.

Comment: Thanks Bill, it's the same result. No rules match the specified criteria. :(

Comment: Do you need to quote the rule name? `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="$rule"` Be sure to use double quotes or the variable won't expand.

Comment: You may also want to refer to this answer, which removes the registry keys directly rather than using `netsh` or `Remove-NetFirewallRule`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915201/696808

Comment: I'm pointing out what was syntactically incorrect in your command. I don't know what else you might be doing wrong as I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you give and example of the profile and display name of a rule that fails your filter? And as a test it might be worth manually running the netsh command for that rule to see if it behaves how you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

Like Bill_Stewart says, and you can also dot reference it.

```
$rulesToRemove = (Get-NetFirewallRule | where {$_.profile -eq "Any"}).DisplayName
foreach($rule in $rulesToRemove) { netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$rule }
```

Comment: Good point. I've tried this, but it's the same, no rules found. I've tried to modify the netsh to show rules which can't be find and the names of the rules are correct. When I enter the names which netsh can't find to Remove-NetFirewallRule, they're deleted with no problem. Only problem is the speed.

Comment: I am not in a place to run this on WS2K16/2K19, just have 2K12R2 nearby, but use the Trace-Command cmdlet to get more detail.

Comment: Just stood up a pristine W2K16 Data Center VM, set a checkpoint, checked the Any rule set, ran the code (after double quoating the $rule variable in the netsh call) posted and all rule are not gone. Rolled back to the chekcpoint, repeated, same successful result. So, thisappears to be something environmental on your side of this effort.

Answer (score 2):

This script will remove most of them; just add the rest if they have similar name. It's not fancy, but it works. The remove-command searches through both in and out firewall lists and removes all that match with the displayname. Run it regularly and it will not use many resources:

```
    Write-Host '*** Deleting: '
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Your account" 
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Work or school account"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "cortana"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "SmartScreen"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Windows Default Lock Screen"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Windows Shell Experience"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Xbox Game UI"
    remove-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Email and accounts"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a reg edit to stop this from happening once you've deleted the orphaned rules.

Addresses an issue that slows server performance or causes the server to stop responding because of numerous Windows firewall rules. To enable this solution, use regedit to modify the following and set it to 1:

```
Type: “DeleteUserAppContainersOnLogoff” (DWORD)
Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar performance problem with `Disable-NetFirewallRule`:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | %{Disable-NetFirewallRule -Name $_.Name}
```

took about 2.5 minutes for 243 rules

**The key is to use an array in the Name parameter.**

```
Disable-NetFirewallRule -Name (Get-NetFirewallRule | select -ExpandProperty Name)
```

took about 15 seconds

**But there is a quota for the Disable-NetFirewallRule** (424 rules was too many). The rrror message is `Quota violation: HRESULT 0x8004106C`, so I guess, that it is a WMI quota. Unfortunatelly I have no detailed information about this error.